# Hide div and show onclick using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to hide and show a div using javascript in my website.
But i want it to be hidden by default and be able to show and hide it on click.
My code seems okay and when I click the button, the display:none; turns into a display:block; but the div doesn't show…

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
    <button href="#collapse1" class="nav-toggle">Show</button>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 portfolio-item" id="collapse1" style="display:none">
    <img src="img/myimage.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
</div>
```

Here's the JS

```
// Show or hides div
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nav-toggle').click(function(){
        //get collapse content selector
        var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('href');                   

        //make the collapse content to be shown or hide
        var toggle_switch = $(this);
        $(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function(){
          if($(this).css('display')=='none'){
                //change the button label to be 'Show'
                toggle_switch.html('Show');
          }else{
              //change the button label to be 'Hide'
              toggle_switch.html('Hide');
          }
        });
    });

});
```

[And here's the example on my website](http://iampox.com/#portfolio)

Comment: `if($(this).css('display')=='none')` might be better written as `if ($(this).is(':hidden'))`

Comment: Seems to work here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/n7dtmzyd/. And you can condense it to just http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4je77foe/. Also,  href isn't a valid attribute for button elements. You could use a custom data attribute instead though `data-href="#collapse1"`

Comment: Even on your site it seems to work

Comment: I've tested it in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, and it only seems to work in Chrome. And yet, as soon as I refresh the page in Chrome, it doesn't work anymore…

Answer (score 0):

I checked up your website and I can see that it changes state from "Show/Hide" on button as well as removing style or adds it to the div that is hidden, but however your image width and height is 0...

Perhaps like this ?

```
<img src="http://iampox.com/img/portfolio/Visuel_JPO_ESTEN_thumbnail@2x.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Visuel JPO ESTEN 2014" width="100%" height="100%" />
```

And here's simplified JS fiddle, since you asked "how to show/hide a div" in your question, so I used a button and hidden content just for sample demo. Perhaps you can minimize your script to something like this.

[JS Fiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/dvLden/u22w68fw/2/)

```
$('#btn').on('click', function () {
    var btnText = ($(this).text() == 'Show') ? 'Hide' : 'Show';

    $(this).text(btnText);
    $('#content').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the image width and height are well defined (width="360" height="260")
I've just forgotten to paste them in my question.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I saw that width and height of your image inside of "hidden" container is `w: 0; h: 0`. Now I can't check again because you removed that from the website. But, at least that was the only problem I noticed for not showing hidden content from hidden container after button click.